# Sending html with message in email using file path

Tags: java, html, email, message, filepath

[image: Like this i need to attach html in message part]I have attached my example source here. I have a html template and path in system. My objective is need to send the HTML template with message in mail. But i have to append the HTML message using html path. How to do this.

```
public class SendMail {
public void sendingEmailToClient(String sEmail,String sUserName,String htmlPath) throws Exception{
    String fromMerchant=null;
    String merchantPassword=null;
    String toClientMail=null;
    String userName=null;
    String smtp=null;
    String smtpServer=null;
    String smtpSocketFactory=null;
    String smtpPort=null;
    String socketFactoryClass=null;
    String sslSocketFactory=null;
    String smtpAuthentication=null;
    String smtpAuthenticateState=null;
    String mailSmtpPort=null;
    if(sEmail!=null && !sEmail.isEmpty() && sUserName !=null && !sUserName.isEmpty()){
        toClientMail=sEmail;
        userName=sUserName;
        System.out.println("The user name is ==>"+userName);
        fromMerchant="vikki@gmail.com";
        merchantPassword="passw0rd";
        Properties properties=new Properties();
        smtp="mail.smtp.host";
        smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com";
        smtpSocketFactory="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port";
        smtpPort="465";
        socketFactoryClass="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class";
        sslSocketFactory="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
        smtpAuthentication="mail.smtp.auth";
        smtpAuthenticateState="true";
        mailSmtpPort="mail.smtp.port";
        properties.put(smtp,smtpServer);
        properties.put(smtpSocketFactory, smtpPort);
        properties.put(socketFactoryClass, sslSocketFactory);
        properties.put(smtpAuthentication, smtpAuthenticateState);
        properties.put(mailSmtpPort,smtpPort);
        Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                return new PasswordAuthentication ("vikki@gmail.com","passw0rd");
            }
        });
        try{
            MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("LoyaltyCart"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(toClientMail));
            message.setText(" Hi "+userName+"\n You have successfully registered on YourShopping !!.. \n We heartly welcomes you and save your money, buy new products...");
          **//Need to append the HTML template using file path with message like message.setHTMLTemplate**
            Transport.send(message);  
            System.out.println("message sent successfully");  
            message.setText("You have successfully registered on YourShopping !!..");
            message.setText("We heartly welcomes you and save your money, buy new products...");
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Are you trying to read a HTML file in the working directory, and append the content in the HTML to the e-mail?

Comment: Do you want the HTML to be an attachment, or part of the text?

Comment: Yes mob. I need to read html using file path then need to append in the message part. After sending mail it should showing with html in email

Comment: I have update my changes. You can see the image how my mail message part should be. Like this image i have a html template. I need to show it using file path

Comment: @MuthuVikki ...the HTML file is local or web?

Comment: Your question was exactly the same with the duplicate specified by @gfelisberto

Comment: Not quite a duplicate;  that other question does not address how to make direct use of a file for message content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an HTML file as the content of your message, you can ues [setDataHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setDataHandler-javax.activation.DataHandler-):

```
String htmlFileName = "/home/vikki/Documents/MailTemplate.html";
message.setDataHandler(
    new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(htmlFileName)));
```

If you want to make the HTML file an inline attachment:

```
String htmlFileName = "/home/vikki/Documents/MailTemplate.html";

MimeBodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
part.attachFile(htmlFileName);
part.setDisposition(Part.INLINE);

message.setContent(new MimeMultipart(part));
```

Both approaches merely provide flat HTML content.  If the HTML includes images, it will need to link to them using external URLs (probably Internet URLs).  Most e-mail clients block links to external images by default.  You can avoid this by attaching each image, and modifying the HTML to point to each image's [Content-Id](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimePart.html#getContentID--) as explained in [RFC 2392](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392), though it will make the message itself larger.